# Image preview before uploading image jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way to implement the fileReader() in IE. i searched a lot but didn't find any solution. This my code where i am trying to implement it. It's working fine in firefox and in chrome but it isn't workink in IE8 and IE9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#img_prev')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                        .height(200);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        </script>

        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style>
        article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
        menu, nav, section { display: block; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img id="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `isn't working`? Do you get any error message?

Comment: thnx for reply its workin in firefox and chrome but in ie image preview is not showing i serched lots on net but didn't get ny solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah i got only one solution. IE 9 don't support File Reader so we can disable image preview for file reader for rest browsers it will work perfectly.