# Upload image with ajax and display to user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to upload an image to a temp folder and display the uploaded image to the user.

The image does upload to the temp folder but the image doesn't display to the user. I rather get a upload_complete message where the image is supposed to be displayed.

Any help in what i'm doing wrong please?

**Javascript**

```
   <script>
        var hasImage = "";
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            if (hasImage != "") {
                return "You have not posted your image";
            }
        }

        function showBtnDiv() {
            _("statustext").style.height = "80px";
            _("btns_SP").style.display = "block";
        }

        function doUpload(id) {
            // www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/File-Upload-Progress-Bar-Meter-Tutorial-Ajax-PHP
            var file = _(id).files[0];
            if (file.name == "") {
                return false;
            }
            if (file.type != "image/jpeg" && file.type != "image/gif") {
                alert("That file type is not supported.");
                return false;
            }
            _("triggerBtn_SP").style.display = "none";
            _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = "Image uploading......";
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("stPic", file);
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
            ajax.open("POST", "php_parsers/photo_system.php");
            ajax.send(formdata);
        }

        function completeHandler(event) {
            var data = event.target.responseText;
            var datArray = data.split("|");
            if (datArray[0] == "upload_complete") {
                hasImage = datArray[1];
                _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = '<img src="tempUploads/' + datArray[1] + '" class="statusImage" />';
            } else {
                _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = datArray[0];
                _("triggerBtn_SP").style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        function errorHandler(event) {
            _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
            _("triggerBtn_SP").style.display = "block";
        }

        function abortHandler(event) {
            _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
            _("triggerBtn_SP").style.display = "block";
        }

        function triggerUpload(e, elem) {
            e.preventDefault();
            _(elem).click();
        }

        function postToStatus(action, type, user, ta) {
            var data = _(ta).value;
            if (data == "" && hasImage == "") {
                alert("Type something first weenis");
                return false;
            }
            var data2 = "";
            if (data != "") {
                data2 = data.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/n/g, "<br />").replace(/r/g, "<br />");
            }
            if (data2 == "" && hasImage != "") {
                data = "||na||";
                data2 = '<img src="permUploads/' + hasImage + '" />';
            } else if (data2 != "" && hasImage != "") {
                data2 += '<br /><img src="permUploads/' + hasImage + '" />';
            } else {
                hasImage = "na";
            }

            _("statusBtn").disabled = true;
            var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_parsers/status_system.php");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                    var datArray = ajax.responseText.split("|");
                    if (datArray[0] == "post_ok") {
                        var sid = datArray[1];
                        var currentHTML = _("statusarea").innerHTML;
                        _("statusarea").innerHTML = '<div id="status_' + sid + '" class="card"><div class="card-profile-title"><div class="row"><div class="col s1"><img src="images/yuna.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img valign profile-post-uer-image"></div><div class="col s10"><p class="grey-text text-darken-4 margin"><a href="#" >Posted by you just now:</a></p><span class="grey-text text-darken-1 ultra-small">Shared - Just now</span></div><a href="#" onmousedown="deleteStatus(\'' + sid + '\',\'status_' + sid + '\');"><i class="mdi-action-delete small tooltipped" data-tooltip="delete this post" data-position="top"></i></a></div></div><div class="card-image profile-medium"><img src="images/gallary/33.jpg" alt="sample" class="responsive-img profile-post-image profile-medium activator"></div><div class="card-content"><p>' + data2 + '</p></div><ul class="card-action-buttons"><li><a class="btn-floating  waves-effect waves-light green accent-4 tooltipped activator right" data-tooltip="comment" data-position="top"><i class="mdi-editor-mode-comment"></i></a></li></ul><div class="card-reveal"><span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><i class="mdi-navigation-close right"></i></span><div class="row"><div class="col s2"><img src="images/yuna.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img valign profile-post-uer-image"></div><div class="col s8"><p>' + data2 + '</p><div class="grey-text text-darken-1 ultra-small right">Just now</div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="input-field col s8 margin"><input id="replytext_' + sid + '" onkeyup="statusMax(this,250)" type="text" class="validate margin"><label for="replytext_' + sid + '">Comment</label></div><i id="replyBtn_' + sid + '" onclick="replyToStatus(' + sid + ',\'<?php echo $u; ?>\',\'replytext_' + sid + '\',this)" class="mdi-content-send small right"></i></div><div id="statuss_' + sid + '"></div></div></div>' + currentHTML;
                        _("statusBtn").disabled = false;
                        _(ta).value = "";
                        _("triggerBtn_SP").style.display = "block";
                        _("btns_SP").style.display = "none";
                        _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = "";
                        _("statustext").style.height = "20px";
                        _("fu_SP").value = "";
                        hasImage = "";
                        $('#post').closeModal();
                    } else {
                        alert(ajax.responseText);
                    }
                }
            }
            ajax.send("action=" + action + "&type=" + type + "&user=" + user + "&data=" + data + "&image=" + hasImage);
        }
   </script>
```

**CSS**

```
.hiddenStuff{
    display: none;
}
.triggerBtn{
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right: 500px;
}
img.statusImage{
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap" >
<div id="left"><div class="fullwidth" id="uploadDisplay_SP"></div></div>  
<div id="right"><textarea id="statustext" onkeyup="statusMax(this,250)" onfocus="showBtnDiv()" class="boxsizingBorder" placeholder="Write something and add a image to your post"></textarea>
<div id="btns_SP" class="hiddenStuff">
    <button id="statusBtn" class="pull-right cenbtn btn btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" onclick="postToStatus('status_post','a','.$u.','statustext')">Post</button>
    <img src="images/camera.jpg" id="triggerBtn_SP" class="triggerBtn" required="required" onclick="triggerUpload(event, 'fu_SP')" width="24" height="24" title="Upload A Selfie" />
    </div>
    <div id="standardUpload" class="hiddenStuff">
    <form id="image_SP" required="required" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" required="required" name="FileUpload" id="fu_SP" onchange="doUpload('fu_SP')"/>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>  </div>
```

**photo_system.php**

```
if (isset($_FILES["stPic"]["name"]) && $_FILES["stPic"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
    $fileName = $_FILES["stPic"]["name"];
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["stPic"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["stPic"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["stPic"]["size"];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["stPic"]["error"];  
    $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExt = end($kaboom);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
    if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
        echo"Image is too small|fail";
        exit(); 
    }
    $time = time();
    $db_file_name = $log_username.time().".".$fileExt;
    if($fileSize > 4096000) {
        echo "Your image file was larger than 4mb fail";
        exit(); 
    } else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
        echo "Your image file was not jpg, gif or png type|fail";
        exit();
    } else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
        echo "An unknown error occurred|fail";
        exit();
    }   
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../tempUploads/$db_file_name")){
        echo "upload_complete|$db_file_name";
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `echo "upload_complete|$db_file_name";` exactly? Did you mean `echo $db_file_name;`?

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747116/image-preview-before-uploading-image-jquery .

Comment: @DelightedD0D echo "upload_complete|$db_file_name"; echos back to the javascript and javascript looks for upload_complete in echo if found it supposed to display the uploaded image

Comment: Have you checked exactly what is returned from the ajax request? Are there any warnings or errors? You could use output buffering to ensure nothing dirties the response since you are relying on the format being exactly what you expect.

Comment: What is the value of `data` immediately after you call `var data = event.target.responseText;`? Is it `upload_complete|`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D its "upload_complete|TheFilename.jpg"; then i split it and check for upload_complete if its found then image will be displayed

Comment: But you have confirmed that when you set a break point at that line, the value really is `upload_complete|TheFilename.jpg` right?

Comment: It seems likely that the value there is not actually what you expect . [This test](http://jsfiddle.net/1gofctr4/2/) seems to show that your code would work  if the value was as expected. Are you sure that there is no whitespace in front of `upload_complete` [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/1gofctr4/3/) shows that such a whitespace would cause exactly the behaviour you see. Remember the response text will be **everything** your script outputs so if you have something like `echo " ";` somewhere before the line that'll give it a space in the return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting words printed to the display instead of an image, it means that your code is hitting the following line:

```
        else {
            _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = datArray[0]; // this line is hit
            //.....
        }
```

Which means the response failed this test:

`if (datArray[0] == "upload_complete") ....`

Since you are seeing the words `upload_complete` on your display, the only possible cause I can see is that your response has some rouge whitespace at the beginning. [See this test that shows such behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/1gofctr4/3/)

Remember the response text will be everything your script outputs so if you have something like echo " "; somewhere before the line, that'll give it a space in the return

TO avoid this, you could call trim on the string or use a regular expression like this:

```
function completeHandler(event) {
            var data = event.target.responseText;
            if (data.match(/upload_complete\|(.+)/)) {
                hasImage = data.match(/upload_complete\|(.+)/)[1];
                _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = '<img src="tempUploads/' +hasImage+ '" class="statusImage" />';
            } else {
                _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = data;
                _("triggerBtn_SP").style.display = "block";
            }
}
```

Comment: this worked perfect sir appreciated the jsfiddle helped alot thank you